# Uncaught TypeError: c is not a constructor, issue only when creating bar graph

Tags: extjs

I have data I have tried to put into a simple bar graph from a local store variable I created. The data goes fine into a traditional table, but get this strange error when trying to create a graph... If i comment out the "axes" the code compiles.. if i leave it in i get this message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koVPM.png)

Code for graph is below... the code base is large so just sending this small snipit

success: function(response){

```
                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                console.log(obj);
                var storeCost = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                    fields:[ 
                        {name: 'nameStart',type: 'string'},
                        {name: 'nameEnd',type: 'string'},
                        {name: 'nameUnit',type: 'string'},
                        {name: 'value',type: 'int'}
                        ]
                });   
                console.log('store created');

                var costList =[];

                for (let i = 0; i < obj.ResultsByTime.length; i++) {    
                    costList.push({nameStart:obj.ResultsByTime[i].TimePeriod.Start, nameEnd:obj.ResultsByTime[i].TimePeriod.End ,nameUnit:obj.ResultsByTime[i].Total.BlendedCost.Unit ,value:Math.round(obj.ResultsByTime[i].Total.BlendedCost.Amount)})   
                }

                storeCost.loadData(costList);

                Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                    layout:'fit',
                    height: 250,
                    width: 500,
                    items:{

                        xtype: 'cartesian',
                        renderTo: document.body,
                        width: 600,
                        height: 400,
                        store: {
                            fields: ['name', 'value'],
                            data: [{
                                name: 'metric one',
                                value: 10
                            }, {
                                name: 'metric two',
                                value: 7
                            }, {
                                name: 'metric three',
                                value: 5
                            }, {
                                name: 'metric four',
                                value: 2
                            }, {
                                name: 'metric five',
                                value: 27
                            }]
                        }, axes: [{
                            type: 'numeric',
                            position: 'left',
                            title: {
                                text: 'Sample Values',
                                fontSize: 15
                            },
                            fields: 'value'
                        }, {
                            type: 'category',
                            position: 'bottom',
                            title: {
                                text: 'Sample Values',
                                fontSize: 15
                            },
                            fields: 'name'
                        }],
                        series: {
                            type: 'bar',
                            subStyle: {
                                fill: ['#388FAD'],
                                stroke: '#1F6D91'
                            },
                            xField: 'name',
                            yField: 'value'
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"*c is not a constructor*" errors tend to be due to a class missing in the [requires array](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-requires).

Since you narrowed it down to the "axes" section, I would assume these entries need to be added to the requires array in your class:

```
requires: [
    'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Category'
]
```